# "This method is undefined for the type Object"

Tags: object

Alright, so I'm very new to programming and was watching a tutorial to get started. A couple hours in and several different tutorials and videos, I thought I had finally figured one out. I just ran into this problem at the end and can't seem to figure it out. When I tried searching for an answer, I got very confused at the answers I was getting. If anyone can explain in very simple terms, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public RSObject findNearest(int distance, int... ids) {
    RSObject[] objects = Object.findNearest(distance, ids);

    for (RSObject object : objects) {
        if (object != null) {
            return object;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

The only error I am running into is the "findNearest." It gives me this error message

"The method findNearest(int, int[]) is undefined for the type Object"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should tag the question with the language you are using. [tag:object] is pretty useless by itself.

Comment: Good point, I'm using Java